# JHipster: how to fix wrong URL in yarn test after upgrade?

Tags: jhipster, api-gateway

I'm building a microservices application using JHipster.
After upgrading the gateway from JHipster 4.13.3 to 4.14.1,
running `jhipster upgrade` inside the gateway application root, I got some errors related to wrong urls of an entity CRUD controller.
Here the log:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Service Tests Company Service Service methods should call correct URL FAILED
    Expected 'undefinedordas/api/companies/123' to equal 'undefined/ordas/api/companies/123'.
    webpack:///src/test/javascript/spec/app/entities/company/company.service.spec.ts:38:48 <- spec/entry.ts:118106:48
    invoke@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:0 <- spec/entry.ts:123093:31
    onInvoke@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126599:45
    invoke@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:0 <- spec/entry.ts:123092:40
    run@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:0 <- spec/entry.ts:122843:49
    webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:106:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126760:37
    execute@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:134:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126788:46
    execute@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:134:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126788:46
    execute@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:134:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126788:46
    execute@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:134:0 <- spec/entry.ts:126788:46
    invokeTask@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:0 <- spec/entry.ts:123126:36
    runTask@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:0 <- spec/entry.ts:122893:57
    drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:594:0 <- spec/entry.ts:123299:42
    run@webpack:///node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:87:0 <- spec/entry.ts:120862:29
    webpack:///node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:100:0 <- spec/entry.ts:120875:31
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in the generated files ([related commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/76e4ac323042d86db55af902962c148a4cdf6646)) that removed a `/` from the entity API url in the entity service files.  This was done so that the entity services use a relative path instead of an absolute path.

While it should have been changed for you automatically through the `jhipster upgrade` subgenerator, you can also fix it manually by removing the extra `/` in your entity service.

Related, do you have a `SERVER_API_URL` variable defined in your `webpack.common.js`?  That appears to be "undefined".

Comment: Ok, I removed the `/` from the company.service.spec.ts file and now the test is successful.
Yes the SERVER_API_URL is defined but as an empty string. 
SERVER_API_URL: `''` under plugins new webpack.DefinePlugin. Is it ok?

Comment: It should be fine.  For reference, the test generation was fixed later in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/52a1d14ed717f37b3378e428ea4884371c1b1feb but this won't be released until v5

Comment: Guys fix it and release please, I spend a lot of time to find the reason of build failure. I thing not me only.